# Xcode 7.2 can't find Alamofire, error: No such module 'Alamofire'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to include Alamofire in my Swift project following the github(https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#cocoapods) instruction.

I've created a new project, navigated to the project directory and run this command sudo gem install cocoapods. Then I faced following error as like my below image can some one help me please

[image]

Comment: delete your pod and pod.lock file , and go to the terminal and locate your project folder and enter the command "pod install"

Comment: in podfile we are mention which library have to install if delete how can we access them?

Answer (score 0):

**It May be helped -**

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz6Tr.png)

**Click on Plus button and add Alamofire.**

Comment: in added them but still same result

Comment: please connect now

Comment: i am installing almofire pods please wait

Comment: Yes Please tell me, And delete above useless comments.

Comment: please accept my mail request i will talk you there if you dont mind

Comment: i sent you invitation in gmail

Answer (score 0):

> I Hope you followed All the Steps for Installing ** Alamofire** correctly and have latest version installed

**Then Follow This Step:**

Step 1 :

> Import Alamofire

Step 2 :

> Keep on Pressing Build ( Cmd + B)

Step 3:

> If Issue Continues then just close your Current program for a moment
>   by completely closing it **(cmd + Q)** and then Re-start it and Follow
>   Step 1 & 2 This will work

Thanks